# How to get delivery report on smpp port kannel

Tags: smpp, kannel

I have below mentioned configuration for kannel the transmitter and reciever port are different.I am able to send sms from transmitter port. How may I get delievery report on reciever port on kannel do i need to add dlr-url to get the smpp response on reciever port , Please suggest as I am new to kannel.Below mentioned is the kannel.conf files.

````
group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = SMSC01
allowed-smsc-id = SMSC01
host = *********
port = 5592
receive-port = 0
transceiver-mode = 0
system-type = SMPP
smsc-username = ******
smsc-password = ******
source-addr-ton = 5
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
max-pending-submits = 3
throughput = 100
msg-id-type = STRINGS
source-addr-autodetect = yes
reconnect-delay = 5
alt-charset = "ASCII"
log-file = "/etc/kannel/logs/smsc01.log"

Reciever Port

group = smsc
smsc = smpp
smsc-id = SMSC02
allowed-smsc-id = SMSC02
host = **********
port = 0
receive-port = 5596
transceiver-mode = 0
system-type = SMPP
smsc-username = ******
smsc-password = ******
source-addr-ton = 5
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
max-pending-submits = 3
throughput = 100
msg-id-type = STRINGS
source-addr-autodetect = yes
reconnect-delay = 5
log-file = "/etc/kannel/logs/smsc02.log"
dlr-url = "http://**********************/"```
````

Answer (score 1):

Set the `smsc-id` (also the `allowed-smsc-id`) to the same value for both groups (i.e. both for transmitter and receiver) but use different `smsc-admin-id` names for each group. That way you'll have both sessions with the same SMSC ID and Kannel will know to correlate outgoing messages with their incoming delivery reports. Multiple SMSC groups with the same `smsc-id` are allowed in Kannel.

`smsc-admin-id` is described in "Table 7-1. SMSC Group Variables" in [Kannel documentation](https://kannel.org/download/1.4.5/userguide-1.4.5/userguide.html) which is where the generic parameters are listed that apply to every kind of SMS center.